# Send Acknowledgement to Sender in Spring Integration : tcp-in/out-channel-adapter

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have made distributed applications.
1. Web Application and 2. Spring Integration Console Application.

I can send data from one to other and do background work using console application but I want acknowledgement that data received receiver side to sender.

Sender should get acknowledgement.

My code :

**Web Application Side(Sender/Client) :**

xml :

```
    <bean id="javaSerializer" class="org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer"/>
    <bean id="javaDeserializer" class="org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer"/>
    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client" host="localhost" port="56565" single-use="true" so-timeout="10000" deserializer="javaDeserializer" serializer="javaSerializer"/>
    <int:channel id="input" />
    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundClient" channel="input" connection-factory="client"/>
```

code while login :

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/esb/sender/sender-esb.xml");
    MessageChannel esbChannel = applicationContext.getBean("input",MessageChannel.class);
    Message<String> esbMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(form.getPatronID()).build();
    esbChannel.send(esbMsg);
```

**Spring-Integration Application side(server / receiver) :**

xml :

```
    <bean id="javaSerializer" class="org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer"/>
    <bean id="javaDeserializer" class="org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer"/>
    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server" type="server" host="localhost" port="56565" single-use="true" so-timeout="10000" deserializer="javaDeserializer" serializer="javaSerializer"/>
    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundServer" channel="inputChannel" connection-factory="server"/>
    <int:channel id="inputChannel"> <int:queue capacity="100" /></int:channel>
    <int:channel id="outputChannel"/>
    <int:service-activator id="loginChannel" input-channel="inputChannel" ref="ESBReceiver" method="getDataFromGL" output-channel="outputChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="500" error-channel="outputChannel" />
    </int:service-activator>
    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="esbLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
    <int:wire-tap channel="esbLogger"></int:wire-tap>
```

java code to fetch request :

run app :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/receiver/receiver-esb.xml");
    }
```

class to process request :

```
    @Component
    public class ESBReceiver {
        public void getDataFromGL(String msg){
            System.out.println("From GL We Get :: " + msg);
            System.out.println("Length :: " + msg.length());
        }
    }
```

in ESBReceiver class I am logging data about user login time and logout time.

I want to send acknowledgement from this class to my web application.
So is it possible ? if yes then any guidance please.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send a reply when the server is done; use tcp gateways instead of channel adapters.

If you want to send an asynchronous message, use [collaborating channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#d4e10814).

Comment: @Garu Russell : Sir, I am doing log in and log out entry using spring integration. I am passing user id of user when log in and at logout time. Am I doing right thing or not ? I have done above code so any modification on it.if user password is wrong then I am sending mail to him just for testing purpose and one thing is that I want 2 way communication for both, both application can send and receive data to each other so for that what I will have to do ? Please any guidance sir.. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as @Gary Russell told you, you can use tcp gateway for it.

Example :

```
   <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="inGateway"
    request-channel="tcpChannel"
    reply-channel="replyChannel"
    connection-factory="cfServer"
    reply-timeout="10000"/>   

   <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="tcpChannel"
    reply-channel="replyChannel"
    connection-factory="cfClient"
    request-timeout="10000"
    remote-timeout="10000"/>
```

[Here's full documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways) Look on it.

Comment: sir will you give me small example of it if possible ? I am new to it so I am totally confused. Thank You.

Comment: There's a [gateway sample here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server) (client and server side). Completely asynch two-way is a bit more complex; you have to use collaborating adapters as I described in my answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell : Sir if you don't mine will you tell me that how to make 2 way communication ? is it possible that one message I want to send all subscriber and one to only selected subscriber then what to do ? Any filtering ?

Comment: Of course; anything is possible, but I don't have time to write your application for you. You will need to do some research on your own and come back here with specific questions if you have any.